# How to deploy a serverless application in openFaaS similar to AWS lambda with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, openfaas

I want to deploy a serverless application on openFaaS. It should be similar to the following example application with AWS Lambda using a S3 trigger: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

So far I have not been able to find anything similar to use with openFaaS to result in the same functionality for this use case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar example using `openfaas`, `minio` and `Tensorflow`. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/viveksyngh/openfaas-pipeline

Let me know if you any question. Happy to help.